# Making an unclickable radio button

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm looking to create a particular broken interface: enabled radio buttons that cannot be clicked but do some action `onClick`. I can write the `onClick` function but the radio button always selects and stays selected. I'm using ReactJS but I don't think that will make a difference.

The first thing I tried:

```
<input type="radio"/>
<input type="radio"/>
<input type="radio"/>
<input type="radio"/>
```

But the problem is that multiple buttons are selectable there and clicking a button causes a selection. I also tried

```
<input type="radio" disabled/>
<input type="radio" disabled/>
<input type="radio" disabled/>
<input type="radio" disabled/>
```

but then the buttons look disabled, not clickable.

What should I do?

Comment: Before you enter your function onclick then clear the checked. e.g. <input type="radio"  onclick="this.checked = false;  yourfunction();">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="Foo" onclick="this.checked=false">
```

or:

```
<input type="radio" name="foo" value="Foo" onclick="myInput(this)">
<script>
    function myInput(e){
        e.checked = false;
        alert("I'm Clicked!");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try this? It doesn't work for me (due to 'this' pointing to the wrong thing).

Comment: Sorry, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

You can add "disabled" attribute to HTML inputs to make them uninteractable:

```
<input type="radio" disabled>
```

Comment: That would **a:** go against the requirement of "*enabled radio buttons*", and **b:** "*cannot be clicked but do some action `onclick`*". All quotes are from the question.

Comment: @DavidThomas
a: I guess you're right, I missed that one. Not sure why is this a requirement in this case though;
b: does 'disabled' make this impossible? It's gonna be 'onclick', not 'onchange' event

Comment: Yeah, it's a stupid requirement, but I am copying a different broken interface. I tried the 'disabled' option and alas I didn't get the behavior I wanted. It is what it is... Thank you for your help!